# Automate when a UserStory is resolved,upload video from attachment to Yammer as new post as an attachment. The Title of US would be the contents

Tags: azure-devops, yammer

We're trying to automate when UserStories are resolved in Azure Devops, the attached video on the UserStory gets posted as a New Yammer Post where the contents includes the Title of the UserStory and the video is saved as an attachment to the post. This helps our company keep up to date with new functionality added to the system, to try and keep everyone updated with developments each build.

Comment: What's your question? Please, specify exactly what you want.

Comment: How would you accomplish this functionality(the steps you'd need to do), so automating when a user story is resolved in Azure Devops, the attached video to get posted to yammer as a new post with the title being the contents? At the moment this is a manual process.

Comment: Hi, Alex. How the things going now? Does Zappier is a good way for you to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since this feature does not supported by service hook or other UI of Azure Devops.

You can try with one third-party website [Zappier](https://zapier.com/apps/azure-devops/integrations/yammer), and try with [Post Yammer messages for updated Visual Studio Online work items](https://zapier.com/app/editor/64082363?simple=true).

[image]

After click Try it, you will be direct to the page that need you specified the org and Yammer account. Please follow the page step to configure it.

[image]

After configure it, please **edit** the message which you want to achieve:

[image]

And then, according to your demand to specified the configuration of Azure Devops and Yammer **event** condition:

[image]